# WebStorm highlights mongoose document properties as "unresolved variable"

Tags: mongoose, webstorm

When I query the database and try to access a property of a retrieved document, WebStorm highlights the query as an error. Once upon a time there was no such problem, when you could set `@types/mongoose` in the list of libraries, now there is no such library. Can you please tell me how to fix it?

I am doing all the schema and model creation and importing correctly, according to the documentation.

[image]